Numerical data at GPS locations displayed as colored scale
I am very new at any GIS and am using QGIS. I have an Excel table with lat and long and a numerical value, I would like to display the numerical value as a color scale across the gps points, say red for high values green for low or something similar.
Is this possible?
We are trying to find trends across space.

Have you managed to import the data as a point layer?

You need to:

export the Excel table to a CSV file
import the CSV file in QGIS as a Point vector layer
set the Categorized Renderer or the Graduated Renderer for the Point vector layer symbology based on the field containing the numerical value.


thank you, that's a big help

@Jon, please remember to "accept" this answer.

@Jon https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
